# Get items count

Tags: java

i need to get the count of the items elements in each item of the list. For example i have one group list in this list are 5 elements, and on each elements there are also some other items. I need to get these count of the items on each elements list to show them nearby elements name in brackets like:

```
element1 (5)
element2 (7)
...
```

I have a list of the group, then i add elements with the name and id to this list, like:

```
for(Group p: list) { l.add(p.getName(),p.getId());}
```

how can i get the count of each item elements that contains in p? Any suggestions

I have one list of Group

```
  Group
    -Group1
    -Group2
    -Group3
    -Group4
    -...
```

each group item has its own elements

```
  Group
    -Group1
      -el1
      -el2
      -el3
      -el4
      -...   
    -Group2
      -el1
      -el2
      -el3
      -el4
    -Group3
    -Group4
    -...
```

i want to get the count of the last tree elements to show on the Group1 (4) for example

i have two methods in one of them i call the

```
number=r.entrySet().size
```

and get the number of elements that i want but on console, if i call this variable in the second method is it null,

```
 for(Group p: list) { l.add(p.getName()+ "("+number+")",p.getId());}
```

how to call it in the second method, i defined it as static

```
 private static int number;
```

Comment: Unclear what you are asking. Can you please elaborate ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a map `<String, AtomicInteger>`. Use `p.getName()` as the key.

Use this code in the loop to count the elements by name (or any other key you can think of):

```
AtomicInteger counter = map.get( p.getName() );
if( null == counter ) {
   counter = new AtomicInteger();
   map.put( p.getName(), counter );
}

counter.increment();
```